# Create a bijection between two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, associations

Is there a way to create a two-way association or a bijection between two lists of equal length?
I know I can use AssociationThread twice, flipping the arguments, but how can I create a bijective function which associates each element in one list with an element of another, and vice-versa?

Comment: In what way does the solution you mention fall short of what you want?

Comment: @Alan its more clunky: using two variables instead of one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bijective function:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
list2 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
MapThread[(f[#] = #2; f[#2] = #) &, {list1, list2}]

f[2]
(* Out: 6 *)
```

And the `AssociationThread` solution that you mention:

```
f = <|AssociationThread[list1 -> list2], AssociationThread[list2 -> list1]|>;

f[2]
(* Out: 6 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

A short variant of C.E.'s answer

```
f = <|Thread /@ {a -> b, b -> a}|>;

f[2]
```

6

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

A short variant of C.E.'s answer

```
f[lists__List] := Append @@ (AssociationThread @@@ {#, Reverse@#}) &@{lists};

{f[a, b][2], f[a, b][6]}

(*{6, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PositionIndex` with the 'default' argument of `Lookup`:

```
a=AssociationThread[list1,list2];

Lookup[a,#,Sequence@@PositionIndex[a][#]]&/@Join[list1,list2]

(* {5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4}  *)
```

As a function:

```
f[lista_,listb_]:=Module[{a=AssociationThread[lista,listb]},
    Lookup[a,#,Sequence@@PositionIndex[a][#]]&]

bij=f[list1,list2];

bij/@Join[list1,list2]

(* {5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4}  *) 

bij[1]

(* 5 *)

bij[5]

(* 1 *)
```